Gitlab runner is not pulling files in windows VM
Gitrunner is pulling all files & folders on my local machine and running successfully.
Today, when I setup another runner in VM, it is creating the right directory but not pulling files/folder and keeps trying to pull as shown in image
What is the issue?
I am able to pull files manually in VM.
Logs:
Running with gitlab-runner 17.1.0 (fe001d5a)
  on vmname XLz6rBtGw, system ID: s_121a318c
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on DEVECPVM00xxx...
Getting source from Git repository
53:08
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/XLz6rBtGw/0/xxxxx/.git/
WARNING: Failed to terminate process: 1 error occurred:
    * failed to attach the runner process to the console of its parent process: The handle is invalid.
ERROR: Job failed: canceled


Are you sure the files are not at the wanted location?

Also please [edit] your question and add the log message as a code block instead of an image. Images can't be searched and links break

@MichaelKotzjan Updated logs. Yes, files are not getting pulled and it keeps on pulling until i cancel it. You can see logs.

I have the same issue, running a windows 11 VM in virtual box on a windows 11 machine.
